# iFrame limited to 150px height

Tags: joomla, iframe-resizer

I am using the iFrame Resizer script to embed an iFrame here:
http://cfmfloors.com/tilecatalog

The iFrame loads perfectly in other sites, but not this one. Why?

Comment: Can you share some of the code you are using, and the debugging attempts you've taken so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the following code:

```
<iframesrc="//site.site/" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//site.site/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

I changed the code to:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="//site.site/" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//site.site/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script>iFrameResize({log:false},"#myFrame")</script>
```

Now, everything seems to be working fine. All other sites seem to be running fine with the new code, as well, so all is good, now. Though, I have no idea why this one site wouldn't run on the old code while all others did just fine.